# How to change stroke width of svg icon?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have my svg icon with very simple style.
I would like to change stroke width of this icon to 2px. I changed inside svg style stroke width to 2 but the top of the icon has been cut off.

Someone knows how to set this properties to have stroke width: 2 but without any cuts?

https://jsfiddle.net/kgpj1n06/13/

```css
.header__button-icon {
    width: 24px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="header__button-icon" width="21" height="21" viewBox="1.5 2 21 21">
  <defs>
    <style>.a{fill:none;stroke:#200e32;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:1.5px;}</style>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(2.778 2.778)">
    <circle class="a" cx="8.989" cy="8.989" r="8.989"></circle>
    <path class="a" d="M0,0,3.524,3.515" transform="translate(15.24 15.707)"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the viewBox size. As your shape becomes larger, your viewBox needs to become larger too so that it contains the entire expanded shape.

```css
.header__button-icon {
    width: 24px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="header__button-icon" width="21" height="21" viewBox="1.5 1.5 21 21.5">
  <defs>
    <style>.a{fill:none;stroke:#200e32;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:2px;}</style>
  </defs>
  <g transform="translate(2.778 2.778)">
    <circle class="a" cx="8.989" cy="8.989" r="8.989"></circle>
    <path class="a" d="M0,0,3.524,3.515" transform="translate(15.24 15.707)"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Great! I also find out if we set to this CSS class something like that: overflow: visible
That's also work

Comment: @ProteinDev overflow: visible is not good for performance.